# vb .net check if the only open window is current window

Tags: vb.net

i'm working on a project that has several windows that the user opens AFTER clicking on a "start" button. i need to restrict the user by showing an error message if the "start" button is clicked WHEN other windows are still open.

here's what i got for the main window with the "start" button:

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
Dim openForms As New FormCollection()
openForms = Application.OpenForms()

If openForms.Count > 1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR MESSAGE", "Errors", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
Else
    'some codes here
End If
End Sub
```

the problem with the above code, is that not all windows are "disposed" properly, hence it remains in an "open" state even after they are closed. and i am not in the position to edit those other windows. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: vba and vb.net are two different languages, please choose one.

Comment: vb .net sorry..

Comment: Not related - But there's no need to initialize `openForms` to `New FormCollection()` if you're going to immediately assign it a different reference. You should be able to just do `Dim openForms = Application.OpenForms()` (IIRC)

Comment: noted :) thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: "not all windows are "disposed" properly, hence it remains in an "open" state even after they are closed" - his sounds like the _improperly disposed_ forms are hidden (`FormRef.Visible = False`).  You can iterate over the OpenForms collection to find such forms and properly close them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Form2).Any Then
  MessageBox.Show("Opened")
Else
  'Else
End If
```

Comment: there are several forms in the application.. but i'll accept this if there is no other way to check all of the other forms at once.. thank you :)

Comment: If there are several form in the application.. Try to insert `If ElseIf Else Statement`.